# profiles for my users asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have many multiple users stored in a table. What im trying to do is that when a user logs in with his username and password, he would be redirected to his own homepage that has his userid and password. How can i create a profile for every user i have?
Im using asp.net and visual C#

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this question already here:

"...ASP.NET only supports Profiles out-of-the-box with the Web Site option. If you are using a Web Application Project (WAP), then you have to roll your own..."

[What is Webprofile useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154179/what-is-webprofile-useful-for/4155101#4155101)