# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' to type 'ProfileCommon'

Tags: asp.net

I am seeing this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' to type 'ProfileCommon'.

on following code:

ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(TextUsername.Text, true);

I am not sure why...

Comment: Related question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154179/what-is-webprofile-useful-for/4155101#4155101

Comment: Basically your Profile. With Web Application projects you have to perform some extra work to get profiles to work properly - follow the links for sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with **theChrisKent**.It's look like problem in the web.config

Check out the following example for,How to get ProfileCommon object in asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GetProfile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        User Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdGet" runat="server" OnClick="cmdGet_Click" Text="Get Profile" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text=""/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**File: Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class GetProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void cmdGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(txtUserName.Text);
        if (profile.LastUpdatedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            lbl.Text = "No user match found.";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Text = "This user lives in " + profile.FirstName;
        }
  }
}
```

File: Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="String" serializeAs="Binary"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="String" serializeAs="Xml"/>
        <add name="DateOfBirth" type="DateTime" serializeAs="String"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

This example only work when the project type is website.If you want to use ProfileCommon object in Web Application then go through the following link

[Converting Profile Object Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx#Y3876)

**EDIT -II**

As per your comment,Following link might help you

[ASP.NET Profiles in Web Application Projects](http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/)

Comment: Web.Config does not work here because this is a web application NOT and Website so I have to define an inherited class from Profilebase

Comment: i want to post my code of CS file here but it says it exceeds the character limit. How can I post the code in a block?

Comment: @Californicated you can edit your question and paste your code there.  You can format it using the {} button

Comment: Hi ChrisKent, I have removed wverything that relates to profile from Web.config and now operating from .CS file which has this ProfileCommon:profileBase and I have defined all the peoperties in that.

Comment: The last link that you posted seems really helpful and I have tried to implement the code that you posted and I have created a class called "userprofile" which inherits from ProfileBase class and in Web.Config I am giving it a reference like  <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" inherits="UserProfile">. The only problem that I am facing now is that it gives me "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'UserProfile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ok Here is the answer for why I am seeing "The type or namespace name 'UserProfile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  error? It is because The class definition was in my ASPX page's code behind and Web.Config, when I said "<profile Inherits = "UserProfile"> It looks for a .CS file with that name, which does not actually exist. Because Class "userPfofile is defined in some ASPX page's Codebehind, it think that that class does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config if no `<profile />` section is defined, ASP.NET creates a profile object of type DefaultProfile which can cause your error.

The above only applies to Web Sites and not Web Applications.  Since you have indicated you are using a Web Application you should be aware:

- Visual Studio does NOT generate ProfileCommon objects for Web Applications
- You have to access your profile properties using `ProfileBase.GetPropertyValue(PropertyName)`

So you can get a property like this (example from below article):

```
DateTime DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("DateOfBirth"));
```

See this article for more information/examples: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/04/12/the-differences-in-profile-between-web-application-projects-wap-and-website.aspx

Comment: I can not use it web.config. I have to inherit it from Profilebase in .CS file

Comment: @Californicated I have updated my answer to address Web Applications

Comment: I think I should had been more precise;

Comment: I am trying to create a new profile for the user NOT trying to access his profile properies. By the way it is weird that everytime I press enter, it posts my comment instead of going into a new line....

Comment: @Californicated:I have updated my answer.Check out the link mention in EDIT-II section